# Restoring MongoDB dbs and collections from old /data/db

Tags: mongodb, import, dump

I have had a MongoDB running that got accidentially uninstalled without any prior dump-export. I re-installed MongoDB and I still have the files in /data/db.

Is there a way to import the old files from the previous MongoDB installation?

Answer (score 0):

You could run mongod on diffrent folders. In order to do that you should specify dbpath as the command line argument. So, at first run mongod by specifying the dbpath command line argument to point to the folder of your earlier installation. Then perform DBs exports. At this point you shuold shut down mongod and start again using defaults. After mongod is up and running import your DBs.